# How i can connect my real app an android studio so i can run espresso test on

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I have an android app that is already installed to my Nox emulator, I have the whole file with its installation and setup - not folder with files , just the installation file -  I need to connect it to android studio so I can run espresso test on it .

I tried to put the app file in android studio projects but it didn't work .

Comment: I'm not familiar with the nox emulator, did you mean Samsung Knox?
Anyway, to be able to run unit tests and such,
the app must be built in debug mode, and Android Studio must have an ADB connection to the device.

Comment: i want to connect  my APK to android studio , i run my apk on the emulator what i need is to connect it with android so i can run espresso test on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio needs an ADB connection to the emulator. 
Instructions for this are on XDA, https://forum.xda-developers.com/tools/android-studio/how-to-connect-android-studio-nox-app-t3241330

- Start Nox App Player, go to Nox system settings >> turn root mode on >> save changes and restart Nox
- Go to Android settings in Nox >> About Tablet >> Keep clicking Build number until it shows that you are now a developer >> go back to Android settings and you will find the developer options now.
- Go to developer options >> tick USB debugging
- Now in cmd go to the bin folder under the installation path of Nox App Player, input this command: nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001. You will see a successfully connected notice in cmd.
  IF: it shows null or offline, just re-start Nox and try again
- Now Android studio will detect Nox.

Comment: that what i did , but what i need is to connect my app that is not exist in android studio- to be shown in android studio so i can test it , i just have the apk (app) on my nox emullator and i work on it i want to import it on android studio

Comment: So you don't have the source code? just an APK? Maybe you have better luck trying to run the tests using the commandline then (gradle)..

Comment: i decompiled the apk , then open it through android studio- all folders are there , but i can't run it, it requests me to edit configuration , but there is no module it is empty

Comment: I think you should forget about Android Studio, if you don't have the *real* source code of the app (decompiled does not count). Just use APKTool to change some minor settings (set android:debuggable=true in AndroidManifest.xml) and run the tests from the Gradle commandline. Android Studio uses that internally so it will have the same effect.

Comment: I found the following link, this might help. 
Apparently, with the latest Android 3.0 preview (not in the stable Android Studio yet!) you can debug APK's without the source-code.
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-debugger.html

Comment: Thanks FrankkieNL